# Efficient way to "update" an entry in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm wondering if there is an more efficient way to do this:

```
private void updateRelations(String relation, Gene gen) {
        if (relations.containsKey(gen)) {
           HashSet<String> relationDat= relations.get(gen);
           relationDat.add(relation);
           relations.put(gen, relationDat);
        }
        else {
            HashSet<String> relationDat = new HashSet<>();
            relationDat.add(relation);
            relations.put(gen, relationDat);
        }
    }
```

Both Gene and Relation are objects. So what I do is I check if there is already a Gene object (with the same gene ID) and if this is the case I want to add the new found relation as a value. If not I just create a new key value pair. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 8 you can use `computeIfAbsent` - it will add a value associated with the given key if the key is not present in the `Map`.

`computeIfAbsent` returns `the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key`, so it will return either an existing `HashSet` or a newly created `HashSet`, to which you can add the new element :

```
relations.computeIfAbsent(gen, k -> new HashSet<String>()).add(relation);
```

Comment: It is definitely more elegant however is this more efficient? because I see that  containsKey (which I used) and computeIfAbsent both use trees

Comment: The one with the method reference won't work. It should be `key -> new HashSet<>()`

Comment: @IMforty2 In terms of complexity, the two are equivalent. It just saves you the need to write the code that checks if the key is already in the Map yourself. Besides, your code has a redundant `relations.put(gen, relationDat);`. You don't have to `put` the `HashSet` value for the given key if it's already in the `Map`.

Comment: This really reduces the code indeed! When I try the first one I get this error: incompatible types: invalid constructor reference...no suitable constructor found for HashSet(Gene)

Comment: @IMforty2 Oh, now I get it. You should use the second version. My mistake.

Comment: So apparently the type interface is not smart enough because the second one is working!

Comment: Thankyou very much @Eran!

Comment: @IMforty2 It's actually not about type inference. `computeIfAbsent` expects a `Function<Key,Value>` (which in your case is `Function<Gene,HashSet>` and HashSet::new is not a match for this interface).

Comment: @Eran the mappingFunction parameter expects a 1-argument Function, not a 0-argument Supplier. So if you use `HashSet::new` the compiler would try to find a HashSet<String> constructor that accepts a Gene argument. If you are lucky, it won't find one. If you are unlucky, e.g. Gene implements Collection, you get a bug.

Comment: what does: "k -> new HashSet<>()" do? because my compiler says: "paramter k is not used" ?

Comment: @PatrickParker Yes, I realized that and deleted my previous wrong comments. Thanks.

Comment: @IMforty2 `k` is the Gene instance you are looking for in the Map. It allows you to compute the value as a function of the key (if the key is not present in the Map), but in your example the value is not a function of the key, so you don't use it.

Comment: This is indeed a bug prone situation. Just the other day I was doing a `computeIfAbsent()` with `Integer` and `ArrayList::new`, creating new lists with the initial size from the key. That was one confusing `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: @Eran: How to update it with Java 7? Is it okay to clear the map and insert all values again?

Comment: @gaurav there's no point in clearing the map and inserting the values again, since that would be less efficient. You can do something like : `HashSet<String> relationDat= relations.get(gen); if (relationDat == null) { relationDat = new HashSet<>(); relations.put(gen, relationDat);} relationDat.add(relation);`

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code. Check this

```
private void updateRelations(String relation, Gene gen) {
    HashSet<String> relationDat;
    if (relations.containsKey(gen)) {
        relationDat= relations.get(gen);
    } else {    
        relationDat = new HashSet<>();
    }
     relationDat.add(relation);
     relations.put(gen, relationDat);
    }
```

You can use ternary operator instead of `if else` to simplify it further.

```
private void updateRelations(String relation, Gene gen) {
        HashSet<String> relationDat = (relations.containsKey(gen)) ?
         relations.get(gen) : new HashSet<>();
         relationDat.add(relation);
         relations.put(gen, relationDat);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. However, You should not include the line 5:
 `relations.put(gen, relationDat);` 
That code is not necessary as `relationDat` is an objec

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is perfectly handled by a data structure called `Multimap`, from Google `guava's` library.

You can see a `Multimap` as `Map<K, List<V>>` or `Map<K, Set<V>>`. A Multimap is a general way to associate keys with arbitrarily many values.

For instance :

```
private Multimap<Gen, String> relations = HashMultimap.create();

private void updateRelations(String relation, Gene gen) {
    relations.put(gen, relation);
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap)